# How to use QGraphicsScene with QtGui/QGuiApplication?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I created a new Qt 5 project with QtCreator, and added the following lines to it.

`#include <QGraphicsScene>`

// in main():
`QGraphicsScene scene;`

In the .pro file I added:
 `Qt += gui`

The object creation of `QGraphicsScene` is resulting in the segmentation fault.
What point am I missing?

EDIT:

---

I realized now that instead of `QApplication` my rest of the program is using `QtGui/QGuiApplication`.

How to use QGraphicsScene with QtGui/QGuiApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct: with `QApplication` it works for me in both Qt 4.8 and 5.2, but not with `QGuiApplication`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    // With QGuiApplication, QGraphicsScene constructor crashes.
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &app, SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

You're incorrect in stating that the code will compile with just the `gui` module added to the project. Without the `widgets` module, your code won't compile, and this should have been the first hint that you're trying to do something that's not supported.

`QGraphicsScene` is not part of the `gui` module, but of the `widgets` module! All classes in the widgets module are free to assume (and they do!) that you've instantiated `QApplication`, *not* `QGuiApplication`! I've submitted it as [QTBUG-36413](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36413), but - unsurprisingly - it got closed as invalid. It simply is not supposed to work.

If you want to use the `QGuiApplication`, there's a workaround:

The `QApplication` (but not `QGuiApplication`) is keeping a list of all graphics scenes. `QGraphicsScene` assumes that the type of `qApp` is `QApplication`. The list is accessed in `QGraphicsScenePrivate::init()`. The fix is to guard the reference to `scene_list` with a type check on `qApp`:

```
if (qobject_cast<QApplication*>(qApp))
```

You need this in both `QGraphicsScenePrivate::init()` and `QGraphicsScene::~QGraphicsScene()`. I've confirmed that after you recompile Qt, it doesn't crash anymore.

If you're serious about it, you'd have to copy relevant files from Qt's sources to your project, remove the `widgets` module from the project file, and patch things up until they work. Personally I think it's a waste of effort. It's trivial to render a `QGraphicsView` into an arbitrary paint device, without having to actually display it on the screen.